# The derivative of the exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, and a smooth vector field $X \in \mathbb{T}(M)$, we can exponentiate $X$ to give a smooth map $$\mathrm{exp}\colon M\to M$$
$$p\mapsto \mathrm{exp}_p(X(p))$$
How can one express the derivative $d_p \mathrm{exp}\colon \mathbb{T}_pM \to \mathbb{T}_pM$ in terms of X?

Many thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: Hint: Chain rule! I can write up more if you'd some more details. :)

Comment: Yes please I would love some more details! I've been stuck quite a while now :S

Comment: @ Aerinmund Fagelson I would ove details also!